# how do i solve 'Cannot read properties of undefined' in ejs

Tags: ejs, eleventy

i am using ejs as the template language in 11ty. in trying to use 11ty collections, i came up with the following ejs code.

```
---
layout: layouts/base.ejs
title: a list of post
---
<ul>
        <% const posts = collections.post;
                for (let a_post in posts) { %>
                <li> <%- a_post.data.title %> </li>
        <% } %>
</ul>
```

this gives the error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')
```

the nunjucks code works however,

```
ul>
{%- for post in collections.post -%}
  <li>{{ post.data.title }}</li>
{%- endfor -%}
</ul>
```

how can i write the above in ejs

i really have no idea of what i am doing wrong

Comment: If `data` is `undefined` try logging `a_post` to find out what values you are actually iterating over.

Answer (score 0):

The collections.post is what i would refer to as an objects of objects. The for/in loop iterates over **properties** of an obeject. there are two ways to address this

1. Use a for/of loop: this iterates over an **iterable object**

```
<ul>
        <% const posts = collections.post;
                for (let a_post of posts) { %>
                <li> <%- a_post.data.title %> </li>
        <% } %>
</ul>
```

2. Change code to the following

```
<ul>
        <% const posts = collections.post;
                for (let a_post in posts) { %>
                <li> <%- (posts)[a_post].data.title %> </li>
        <% } %>
</ul>
```